# Improving Performance of NIntegrate of a 6D Integral

Tags: numerical-integration

I would like to plot the following function

```
F[k_] := NIntegrate[
    E^(-((y-y1)^2 + (z-z1)^2 + 2 (y^2 + z^2 + y1^2 + z1^2)))/(((x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + I k) ((x1^2 + y1^2 + z1^2) - I k))
    (1/((x-x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2 + (z-z1)^2) + 1/((x+x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2 + (z-z1)^2))  
    Sqrt[(y^2 + z^2) (y1^2 + z1^2)]/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2),
  {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity},
  {x1, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y1, -Infinity, Infinity}, {z1, -Infinity, Infinity},
  PrecisionGoal -> 6, WorkingPrecision -> 10, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

for various k. Unfortunately, this function evaluates very slowly even for a single point. Is there a way to improve the NIntegrate time of this function?

Comment: Generally, for faster integrations use machine precision as a working precision, and "GlobalAdaptive" as an integration strategy. Also experiment and evaluate the results with a small precision goal, e.g. 2.

Comment: Most impact in terms of total integration time would be exploiting the symmetries of your integrand better and thereby reducing the number of dimensions that need to be integrated numerically. E.g. in your case it looks like your integrand has a cylindrical symmetry in `x` and `x1` direction, so you could use `rho==Sqrt[y^2+z^2]` and `phi` and integrate over `phi` analytically, giving a factor of `2 Pi`, same for `rho1`. This would reduce your integration problem to 4 dimensions which should converge much faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with your original expression

```
expr = E^(-((y - y1)^2 + (z - z1)^2 + 
       2 (y^2 + z^2 + y1^2 + z1^2)))/(((x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + I k)
       ((x1^2 + y1^2 + z1^2) - I k))
       (1/((x - x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2 + (z - z1)^2) + 
       1/((x + x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2 + (z - z1)^2))
       Sqrt[(y^2 + z^2) (y1^2 + z1^2)]/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)
```

and change coordinates from the double cartesian `{x,y,z,x1,y1,z1}` to a double cylindrical `{rho,phi,x,rho1,phi1,x1}` coordinate system.

```
rules = Join[
  {y, z, x} -> CoordinateTransformData["Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian", "Mapping", {\[Rho], \[Phi], x}] // Thread,
  {y1, z1, x1} -> CoordinateTransformData["Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian", "Mapping", {\[Rho]1, \[Phi]1, x1}] // Thread
]
```

[image: coordinate mapping]

Now in order to transform our integrand to the new coordinates we also need the determinant of the jacobian of our mapping

```
jacobian = CoordinateTransformData["Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian", "MappingJacobianDeterminant", {\[Rho], \[Phi], x}]*CoordinateTransformData["Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian", "MappingJacobianDeterminant", {\[Rho]1, \[Phi]1, x1}]
```

> $\rho\rho_1$

which is easy for our cylindrical coordinate system. Now the new integrand becomes

```
expr2 = FullSimplify[
  jacobian (expr /. rules), 
  Assumptions -> {\[Rho] > 0, \[Rho]1 > 0, x \[Element] Reals, x1 \[Element] Reals, \[Phi] \[Element] Reals, \[Phi]1 \[Element] Reals}
]
```

[image: new integrand]

If we look closely we can see that we only ever encounter the difference $\phi-\phi_1$, which means we have a rotational symmetry and only need one angular coordinate instead of two. So let's just replace that difference by $\Delta\phi$ and imagine we do an extra analytical integration over the other angular coordinate that we never use from $0$ to $2\pi$, which we have to account for by multiplying our integral value by $2\pi$.

```
expr3 = expr2 /. \[Phi] - \[Phi]1 -> \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi]
```

[image: new integrand with delta phi]

Now we can write your `F[k]` function with the new integrand:

```
F[k_?NumericQ] := 2 \[Pi] NIntegrate[
    (2 E^(-3 (\[Rho]^2 + \[Rho]1^2) + 
  2 \[Rho] \[Rho]1 Cos[\[CapitalDelta]\[Phi]]) \[Rho]^2 \[Rho]1^2 (x^2 + x1^2 + \[Rho]^2 + \[Rho]1^2 - 
  2 \[Rho] \[Rho]1 Cos[\[CapitalDelta]\[Phi]]))/((x^2 + \[Rho]^2) (I k + x^2 + \[Rho]^2) (-I k + 
  x1^2 + \[Rho]1^2) ((x - x1)^2 + \[Rho]^2 + \[Rho]1^2 - 
  2 \[Rho] \[Rho]1 Cos[\[CapitalDelta]\[Phi]]) ((x + 
    x1)^2 + \[Rho]^2 + \[Rho]1^2 - 
  2 \[Rho] \[Rho]1 Cos[\[CapitalDelta]\[Phi]]))
  , {x, -Infinity,Infinity}
  , {\[Rho], 0, Infinity}
  , {\[CapitalDelta]\[Phi], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}
  , {x1, -Infinity,Infinity}
  , {\[Rho]1, 0, Infinity}
  , PrecisionGoal -> 6
  , WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision
  , Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive"}
]
```

where we added the extra factor of $2\pi$, changed the limits to fit our cylinder coordinates and used `"GlobalAdaptive"` as a good starting point for our integration `Method`. Also we changed the `WorkingPrecision` to `MachinePrecision` which means the computations are done with hardware double precision instructions instead of software arbitrary precision library functions. Compared to the original cartesian `F` the results seem much more robust to the singularity in the integrand than before and converge faster.

As an example for $k=1.5$ the original `F` with the `"LocalAdaptive"` `Method`

```
Fcartesian[N[3/2]] // Timing
```

didn't finish in 15 minutes. After switching to `"GlobalAdaptive"` it finishes

> {68.0008, -625.9456805 - 0.8039098772 I}

but still takes quite long, mainly because of the arbitrary precision numbers and part due to the bad convergence and the extra integration dimension. Also the result is very imprecise, probably because our `WorkingPrecision` is too small.

Our new `F` on the other hand gives a reasonably robust result in 7 seconds!

```
F[N[3/2]] // Timing
```

> {6.89524, 6.86588 - 0.908018 I}

There is [great documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateOverview.html) about the different `Method` options for `NIntegrate` which could probably improve the performance for your application even more if you take the time to dig deeper and experiment with different methods and settings.